# Can't upcast pointer to pointer argument

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, upcasting

I can't understand anything here. I expected that if I can pass a dog pointer to function taking animal pointer, I could also pass the &dog to a function that takes a pointer to pointer of Animal.

```
struct Animal{};
struct Dog : Animal{};

void ptrToPtr(Animal** arg){}
void refToPtr(Animal*& arg){}
void refToConstPtr(Animal* const & arg){}
void ptrToConstPtr(Animal* const * arg){}

int main(void)
{
    Dog* dog;
    Animal* animal;

    ptrToPtr(&animal); // Works
    ptrToPtr(&dog); // Argument of type Dog** is incompatible with argument of type Animal**

    refToPtr(animal); // Works
    refToPtr(dog);      // A reference of type Animal*& (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type Dog*

    ptrToConstPtr(&animal); // Works
    ptrToConstPtr(&dog);    // Argument of type Dog** is incompatible with paramater of type Animal* const*

    refToConstPtr(animal); // Works
    refToConstPtr(dog);  // Works. This is the only one that allows me to send Dog to Animal

    return 0;
}
```

I just don't get it, can anyone explain what the reasons are for why particular cases work and others don't? Like passing the dog pointer address to the Animal**, that would be an upcast, wouldn't it?

Comment: *interconvertible* pointer types are pointers to objects of a derived/base type. A pointer to a pointer isn't *interconvertible* with other types. Same applies to references.

Comment: If you could do `ptrToPtr`, you could do `*arg = new Cat;` and `dog` would no longer point to a `Dog`.

Answer (score 3):

*interconvertible* pointer types are pointers to objects of a derived/base type. A "pointer to a pointer" isn't *interconvertible* with other types (with the exception of `void*`). Same applies to references.

This means that given any hierarchy below:

```
struct Animal{};
struct Dog : Animal{};
```

And the following variables:

```
Dog* dptr;
Animal* aptr;
```

`dptr` can be converted to `Animal*` (even implicitly), likewise `aptr` can be converted to `Dog*` (but not implicitly). *Because: up-casting in a class hierarchy is always legal, hence this will be done implicitly by [ICS](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics). However, down-casting isn't always so, so its never done implicitly)*

However:

```
Dog** ddptr;
Animal** aaptr;
```

`ddptr` cannot be implicitly converted to `Animal**`, likewise `aptr` cannot be converted to `Dog**`. Because, they are two different types with no hierarchical relationship.

---

---

---

The above explanation explains why the pointer to pointer overloads fail.
That said, let's deal with the reference type overloads. From your code,

```
refToPtr(animal); // Works
refToPtr(dog);      // A reference of type Animal*& (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type Dog*
```

the second call doesn't work because non-const references of say `X` can only be bound to an exact *glvalue* object of `X`. Since `refToPtr` takes a non-const reference to a `Animal*` type, we can only pass it glvalues of `Animal*` type, which `animal` is, but `dog` isn't.

the last one works, and it's legal because

```
refToConstPtr(animal); // Works
refToConstPtr(dog);    // Works. This is the only one that allows me to send Dog to Animal
```

`const` references of say `X` can be bound to any value catagory of `X`, including temproaries whose lifetimes are extended. Since since we can convert `dog` to `Animal*`. That conversion takes place and a temporary `Animal*` is produced whose lifetime is extended by the `const` reference.

Comment: When you say cannot be implicitly converted, can you force it? I suppose I can with a void pointer.

Comment: @Zebrafish, yes, you can force it. You don't need to go through the `void*` route. You may use `static_cast<Derived*>(baseObjectPtr)` if you are absolutely sure `*baseObjectPtr` was originally of type `Derived`. Or `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(baseObjectPtr)` if you can't be certain... **But no**, this doesn't apply to your question. Because `Animal**` has no relationship with `Dog**`